# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

How does one compute $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}$ without using l'Hôpital's rule or knowledge about the derivative of $e^x$ ? $e^x$ denotes the exponential function with base $e$ (Euler's constant).

Comment: What's your definition of $e^x$? The answer to your question depends upon the this definition.

Comment: Or rather, what is your definition of $e$?

Comment: I would never use l'Hôpital's rule for such a limit. That is the definition of the *derivative* of $e^x$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @MartinR the OP clarified that he doesn't want to use the notion of a derivative.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Taylor series for $e^x$?

Comment: @AndrewChin Many definitions of the function $e^x$ do not refer to the number $e$ at all, and indeed some standard definitions of the constant use the function as a starting point. Since it is the function that appears here, it is more apt to ask how the function is defined, rather than the constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the series definition of the exponential function one obtains:

$\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x} = \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}-1}{x} = \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}}{x} =
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{k!}} =
 1+{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{k!}}  $.

Hence,

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(1+{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{k!}}\right) = 1 + \lim\limits_{x\to 0} {\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{k!}} \stackrel{(1)}{=} 1 + 0 = 1.$

$\phantom{\\}$

(1)  $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} {\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{k!}} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} {\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{(k+2)!}} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} x{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k}}{(k+2)!}} = 0 \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = 0.$

$\phantom{\\}$

**Alternative approach:**

We make the substitution $u = e^x-1$ to obtain

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x}=\lim\limits_{u\to 0} \dfrac{u}{\ln(u+1)} = \lim\limits_{u\to 0} \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{u}\ln(u+1)} = \lim\limits_{u\to 0}\dfrac{1}{\ln((u+1)^{1/u})}$

Now when  substituting $t = 1/u$ it becomes obvious that

$\lim\limits_{u\to 0}\dfrac{1}{\ln((u+1)^{1/u})} = \lim\limits_{t\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{\ln((1/t+1)^{t})} \stackrel{(2)}{=} \left(\ln\left(\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{t}\right)^{\large t}\right)\right)^{\large-1} = (\ln(e))^{-1} = 1.$
$\phantom{\\}$

(2) We use the fact that $\ln(x)$ is continuous at $x=e$.

Answer (score 3):

The evaluation of the limit will *heavily* depend on how you've defined the exponential function $e^{(\cdot)}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (I'll use the $\exp$ notation here). If it's defined as the unique solution of the initial value problem $f'=f,f(0)=1$, then the limit immediately follows from the fact that $(\exp)'(0)=\exp(0)=1$ and the limit definition of the derivative.

\begin{align*}
1 &= (\exp)'(0)\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\exp(0+h)-\exp(0)}{h}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\exp(h)-1}{h}
\end{align*}

If $\exp(x)$ was defined as the sum of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, then the limit can be established by making use of the continuity of power series:

\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\exp(h)-1}{h} &= \frac{\left(1+h+\frac{h^2}{2!}\cdots\right)-1}{h}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{h+\frac{h^2}{2!}+\frac{h^3}{3!}\cdots}{h}\\
&=  \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\left(1+\frac{h}{2!}+\frac{h^2}{3!}\cdots\right)\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

Here are a few more characterizations:

- $\exp(x):=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$
- $\exp$ is the inverse function of $\ln$, where $\ln$ is defined in a way that avoids circularity, e.g. $\ln(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$.
- $\exp$ is the unique function $f$ that is continuous at some point, satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, and satisfies $f(1)=e$, where $e$ is defined in a way that avoids circularity, e.g. $e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$

I’d happily prove that $\lim_{h\to 0}[\exp(h)-1]/h=1$ from one of these characterizations, but my current level of mathematical knowledge prohibits me from doing so. Also, this response was more to draw your attention to the point that different definitions lead to different proofs. Definitions are important!

Comment: Your first approach makes use of the derivative, what the OP wanted to avoid. The second approach is very similar to my first one.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\,a_n:=n(b^{1/n}-1).\,$ Verify that
$$a_n=\frac{n(b-1)}{(b-1)/(b^{1/n}-1)} =
\frac{n(b-1)}{1+b^{1/n}+b^{2/n}+\cdots+b^{(n-1)/n}}. $$
Notice that
$$ \lim_{n->\infty} \frac{1+b^{1/n}+b^{2/n}+\cdots+b^{(n-1)/n}}n
 = \int_0^1 b^x dx = \frac{b-1}{\log b} $$
using Riemann sums **and** that $\,\int b^x dx =\dfrac{ b^x}{\log b}+C.\,$ Thus,
$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{b^x-1}x = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \log b. $$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $0<|x|<1$: By Bernoulli's inequality we have
\begin{align}
e^{+x}&\geq 1+x\tag{1}\\
e^{-x}&\geq 1-x\tag{2}
\end{align}
Inequality $(2)$ is equivalent to
$$e^{x}\leq \frac{1}{1-x}\tag{3}$$
From $(1)$ and $(3)$ we obtain
$$1\leq \frac{e^x-1}{x}\leq \frac{1}{1-x}$$
Squeeze theorem implies then
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

We have :
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}$$
If we considered the following function : $f(x)=e^x$ then :
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}$$
And the derivative of the exponential function is itself, so $f'(0)=e^0=1$, and your limit is :
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$

Comment: It's asked about to prove it without knowing that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ itself

Comment: @Fakemistake Oh I didn't completed the question, sorry !